# In Sharepoint using the Client Object Model, how can I determine if a URL represents a site

Tags: sharepoint

Using managed code, I believe I can do something like the following which can both tell me if the URL is valid, and, if so, if it represents a site.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
       if (url.TrimEnd('/').EndsWith(web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/'))
       {
           // The url represents a site
       }
    }
}
```

I've tried something similar using the Client Object Model.

```
ClientContext context = context = new ClientContext(url);
Web web = context.Web;
context.Load(web);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

As far as I can tell, this will throw an exception if the URL represents something other than a site, like a folder or a library.  That's good as I can use the exception to determine if the URL represents a site.  But I'd also like to be able to differentiate between a URL which is valid but doesn't represent a site, and a URL which is simply not valid.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "a URL which is simply not valid," do you mean a malformed URL, or a correctly-formed URL that doesn't resolve anywhere? I'm pretty sure you mean the former.

If you're just looking for well-formedness, I suggest attempting to parse it into a [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) object:

```
string testUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
Uri goodUri;
if (Uri.TryCreate(testUrl, UriKind.Absolute, out goodUri)) {
    // testUrl == well-formed URI
}
```

I use the `Uri` class a lot, especially before I try to feed it into the SharePoint API for Sites and Webs. I tend to need to hack on it some, either to make a relative URL absolute for my current SP server, or to get parts of the path to resolve to relative locations from the current site.

---

Just for the sake of completeness, if you ever **are** trying to determine if a URL resolves somewhere or not, you can create an HTTP request and test it:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(goodUri);
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
    // Received 200 OK -- probably a valid URL
}
resp.Close();
```

Of course, the HTTP example above is incredibly, naively, simple. There could be all kinds of responses, or requirements for certain request properties to be set, etc. Review the documentation for [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) for more information.